# Use of printf in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, printf

If i have a loop like shown below:

```
    for(k = 0; k < histogram[j]; k++) {
      /* printf("histogram[" + k + "]") */
      printf("*");
    }
```

How do I print what I have in the comments.. I am new to C and used to being able to concatenate things like so.

Comment: `printf("%d", histogram[k]);` Something like this, but this is basic C (See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ And you will be able to figure it out yourself)

Comment: `printf("histogram[%d]", k)` the real format depends on the type of k

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what you want

```
for(k = 0; k < histogram[j]; k++) {
   printf("historgram[%d]", k);
}
```

See also: [printf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)
*Note, the link is to some man docs that I found online, printf for what you are looking to do with this question is the same across systems

Comment: **suggestion**: provide links to function manuals instead of c++ reference, because this is a c question. It's my opinion and it can be wrong.

Comment: thanks, changed the link to be for printf from some linux man docs I found online, for this question printf is the same across every system I've ever used